# why is my string being read this way?

Tags: string, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to recreate atoi and I'm wondering why my function works. I ended up changing it to str[i] for the three top statements because it made sense to me, but it passed everything I threw at it.

```
i = 0;
result = 0;
negative = 1;
if (str[0] == '-')
{
    negative = -1;
    i++;
}
if (str[0] == '+')
    i++;
while (str[0] <= ' ')
    i++;
while (str[i] != '\0')
    if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
    {
        result = result * 10 + str[i] - '0';
        ++i;
    }
return (result * negative);
```

Comment: In your final while-loop, you are ignoring anything that is not a digit. Is that what you meant or should it throw an error? `12A3` will now return `123`.

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement simply checks to see if the number should be a negative.
The second if statement checks to see if the string starts with the optional positive sign
The first while loop should run to infinity if a character who’s ascii is less than the ascii for space(32)
The second while loop simply loops through the string and converts the string to int

Changing the first 3 str[0] to str[i] shouldn’t make much of a difference since i has been initialised to 0. An exception would be if your string started with “-+” which shouldn’t be a valid integer or there’s a space between the signs and the numbers